# Can I bypass the ridiculous obstacle course during the last mission?

Tags: strike-suit-zero

So, during the last mission, you are required to fly through a long winding tunnel while avoiding collisions. I find it ridiculous and infuriating. I'd like to see how the game ends, but I'm not wasting 30 minutes on the obstacle course. Is there any way at all for me to bypass it?

Comment: This reminds me of the last part of Halo 1, where you have to drive the warthog whilst the ship explodes around you. It didn't help that I hadn't learned to control the warthog, having avoided it throughout the rest of the game.

Comment: so wait you want the final prize, while skipping the final challenge? AND YOU CALL YOURSELF A GAMER!? SHAME! SHAMMEEEEEE!!!

Comment: @Ender it's not so much a game as it is a driving test in 3D.

Comment: @kotekzot video game. GAME. Website about GAMES. in VIDEO.

Comment: @Ender that's why I'm asking - I want to get to the game part of the game.

Comment: -,-  sounds suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to completing that mission successfully is to use a joystick or a gamepad to fly instead of the mouse, due to the cursor follow mouse flight mode fine flying is a lot harder with the mouse.

Other things to consider:

- Play on easy, obviously.
- You won't have enough time to destroy the core if you fly the entire course with minimum speed, open her up on straights (and if you want to destroy the limiters, which takes about 3 minutes, on moderate turns as well).
- The white lasers do almost no damage on easy difficulty, while it's better to avoid them, don't take your finger off the afterburner to do so for the best results.
- If you manage to find a trainer that has an infinite armor option, you will be golden; however I could not find such a trainer for the current version, but there's a chance it might pop up in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you've got to play through it in order to see the end.

If you opt to "destroy the limiters" you have an even longer driving test to pass.  I did it, but the clock was down to less than a minute.  The "destroy the core" ending is much faster.

You can use your thrusters to boost a bit and get through it faster, though.  As long as you don't collide with the walls *too* much, you'll survive.  The first hit knocks down your shields, and subsequent hits will hurt your armor a bit.

I didn't drive especially carefully and made it to the end with roughly half my armor on normal.